# Call URL with wget and return an ERRORLEVEL depending on URL's contents

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, cmd

A client has a Windows based in-house server, on which they edit the contents of a CMS. The data are synchronized nightly with the live web server. This is a workaround for a slow Internet connection.

There are two things to be synchronized: New files (already sorted) and a mySQL database. To do this, I am writing a script that exports the database into a dump file using `mysqldump`, and uploads the dump.

The upload process is done using a 3rd party tool named [ScriptFTP](http://www.scriptftp.com), an FTP automation tool.

I then need to run a PHP based import script on the target server. Depending on this script's return value, the ScriptFTP operation goes on, and some directories are renamed.

I need an external tool for this, as scriptFTP only supports FTP calls. I was thinking about the Windows version of **wget**.

Within scriptFTP, I can execute any batch or exe file, but I can only parse **the errorlevel** resulting from the call and not the `stdout` output. This means that I need to return `errorlevel 1` if the PHP import operation goes wrong, and `errorlevel 0` if it goes well. Additionally, obviously, I need to return a positive errorlevel if the connection to the import script could not be made at all.

I have total control over the importing PHP script, and can decide what it does on error: Output an error message, return a header, whatever.

**How would you go about running wget (or any other tool to kick off the server side import) and returning a certain error level depending on what the PHP script returns?**

My best bet right now is building a batch file that executes the wget command, stores the result in a file, and the batch file returning errorlevel 0 or 1 depending on the file's contents. But I don't really know how to match a file's contents using batch programming.

Comment: TMHO, using php-curl would be better then wget

Comment: I can't run PHP on the "client" side, only on the remote server. I am limited to command line tools here.

Comment: If it is a windows server, wouldn't it be easier to write a small C# app that will parse the output and return the proper errorcode?

Comment: Definitely, but I don't speak c# and the last time I built a Windows application in any language was five years ago. :) I would prefer a ready-made tool in this case, I don't mind using something entirely different than wget.

Comment: (Checking Wikipedia what powershell is) (checking Windows version) yes, I can use Powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following in powershell:

```
$a = wget --quiet -O - www.google.com
$rc = $a.CompareTo("Your magic string")
exit $rc
```

Comment: In PowerShell you don't even need `wget`. Just use `System.Ne.WebClient` and its `DownloadString` method.

Comment: Brilliant, this works perfectly. Thank you very much. @Johannes Rössel: Thanks for that tip as well, I will look into it.

Comment: I have a follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044011/powershell-script-cant-read-return-value-of-executed-program if anybody wants to take a look.