# Powershell script: Can't read return value of executed program

Tags: windows, powershell

I am using PowerShell to run a script that executes `wget` to fetch a web page (a simple database import script) and analyzes its output (Error message or "OK").

I am using code from the answer to [**this previous question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034556/call-url-with-wget-and-return-an-errorlevel-depending-on-urls-contents) of mine.

```
$a = c:\path_to_wget\wget.exe --quiet -O - "http://www.example.com/import_db"
$rc = $a.CompareTo("OK")
exit $rc
```

When the result of the wget operation is a 404 - and wget probably returns an errorlevel 1 or 127 - I get the following error message from PowerShell:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

this obviously refers to my calling the `CompareTo()` function.

However, *wget gets executed* and outputs something.

I am suspecting that wget outputs to the error console in this case, and this does not get caught by my $a operation.

**How can I redirect the error output so that it gets caught by my script?**

Boy, I'm sure going to be question king in the PowerShell tag this month! :)

Comment: Short question aside: If you're using PowerShell anyway, why even bother with `wget`? `$wc = New-Object Net.WebClient; $rc = ($wc.DownloadString("http://www.example.com/import_db")).CompareTo("OK")`

Comment: I looked into the WebClient documentation on the hint you gave me in my last question, and shied away from the complexity, hoping for a kind soul who would give me an example to start with. Thanks a lot, this I can work with! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start  with

```
# This will hold the last executed EXE return code
$LastExitCode
# For console apps, where 0 is true, else is false, this will hold either True or False
$?
```

As for reading the STDERR, i guess the quickest way will be to run the script with stream redirection

```
$a = c:\path_to_wget\wget.exe --quiet -O - "http://www.example.com/import_db" 2>&1
```

Comment: If `2>&1` works in this context, I think I'm all right already. Thanks very much!

Comment: I would avoid using $? with console apps.  I've seen too many that don't honor the convention of 0 == success.  Check out the CheckLastExitCode function in this post (I use it in a lot build scripts): http://keithhill.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!5A8D2641E0963A97!7107.entry?wa=wsignin1.0&sa=36637920